# rip adress not visible with dr command

Tags: binary-analysis, radare2, binary, breakpoint

I just finished [this challenge](https://www.root-me.org/fr/Challenges/Cracking/ELF-C-0-protection). This is the content of main function :

```
[0x08048a86]> pdf
/ (fcn) main 417
|   main (int argc, char **argv, char **envp);
|           ; var int local_16h @ ebp-0x16
|           ; var int local_15h @ ebp-0x15
|           ; var int local_14h @ ebp-0x14
|           ; var int local_10h @ ebp-0x10
|           ; var int local_ch @ ebp-0xc
|           ; var int local_8h_2 @ ebp-0x8
|           ; var char *local_4h @ esp+0x4
|           ; var int local_8h @ esp+0x8
|           ; DATA XREF from entry0 (0x80488a7)
|           0x08048a86      8d4c2404       lea ecx, [local_4h]         ; 4
|           0x08048a8a      83e4f0         and esp, 0xfffffff0
|           0x08048a8d      ff71fc         push dword [ecx - 4]
|           0x08048a90      55             push ebp
|           0x08048a91      89e5           mov ebp, esp
|           0x08048a93      53             push ebx
|           0x08048a94      51             push ecx
|           0x08048a95      83ec20         sub esp, 0x20
|           0x08048a98      89cb           mov ebx, ecx
|           0x08048a9a      833b01         cmp dword [ebx], 1
|       ,=< 0x08048a9d      7f4f           jg 0x8048aee
|       |   0x08048a9f      8b4304         mov eax, dword [ebx + 4]    ; [0x4:4]=-1 ; 4
|       |   0x08048aa2      8b18           mov ebx, dword [eax]
|       |   0x08048aa4      c7442404b18d.  mov dword [local_4h], str.usage_: ; [0x8048db1:4]=0x67617375 ; "usage : "
|       |   0x08048aac      c7042460b004.  mov dword [esp], obj._ZSt4cerr__GLIBCXX_3.4 ; [0x804b060:4]=0
|       |   0x08048ab3      e838fdffff     call sym.std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char___std::operator___std::char_traits_char___std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char____charconst
|       |   0x08048ab8      895c2404       mov dword [local_4h], ebx
|       |   0x08048abc      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|       |   0x08048abf      e82cfdffff     call sym.std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char___std::operator___std::char_traits_char___std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char____charconst
|       |   0x08048ac4      c7442404ba8d.  mov dword [local_4h], str.password ; [0x8048dba:4]=0x73617020 ; " password"
|       |   0x08048acc      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|       |   0x08048acf      e81cfdffff     call sym.std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char___std::operator___std::char_traits_char___std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char____charconst
|       |   0x08048ad4      c74424045088.  mov dword [local_4h], sym.std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char___std::endl_char_std::char_traits_char___std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char ; [0x8048850:4]=0xb04425ff
|       |   0x08048adc      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|       |   0x08048adf      e85cfdffff     call sym.std::ostream::operator___std::ostream_____std::ostream
|       |   0x08048ae4      bb05000000     mov ebx, 5
|      ,==< 0x08048ae9      e92b010000     jmp 0x8048c19
|      ||   ; CODE XREF from main (0x8048a9d)
|      |`-> 0x08048aee      8d45eb         lea eax, [local_15h]
|      |    0x08048af1      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|      |    0x08048af4      e867fdffff     call sym.std::allocator_char_::allocator
|      |    0x08048af9      8d45eb         lea eax, [local_15h]
|      |    0x08048afc      89442408       mov dword [local_8h], eax
|      |    0x08048b00      c7442404c48d.  mov dword [local_4h], 0x8048dc4 ; [0x8048dc4:4]=0xca15d618
|      |    0x08048b08      8d45f4         lea eax, [local_ch]
|      |    0x08048b0b      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|      |    0x08048b0e      e80dfdffff     call sym.std::basic_string_char_std::char_traits_char__std::allocator_char__::basic_string_charconst__std::allocator_char_const
|      |    0x08048b13      8d45ea         lea eax, [local_16h]
|      |    0x08048b16      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|      |    0x08048b19      e842fdffff     call sym.std::allocator_char_::allocator
|      |    0x08048b1e      8d45ea         lea eax, [local_16h]
|      |    0x08048b21      89442408       mov dword [local_8h], eax
|      |    0x08048b25      c7442404cc8d.  mov dword [local_4h], 0x8048dcc ; [0x8048dcc:4]=0xaf67b350
|      |    0x08048b2d      8d45f0         lea eax, [local_10h]
|      |    0x08048b30      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|      |    0x08048b33      e8e8fcffff     call sym.std::basic_string_char_std::char_traits_char__std::allocator_char__::basic_string_charconst__std::allocator_char_const
|      |    0x08048b38      8d45ec         lea eax, [local_14h]
|      |    0x08048b3b      8d55f4         lea edx, [local_ch]
|      |    0x08048b3e      89542408       mov dword [local_8h], edx
|      |    0x08048b42      8d55f0         lea edx, [local_10h]
|      |    0x08048b45      89542404       mov dword [local_4h], edx
|      |    0x08048b49      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|      |    0x08048b4c      e83cfeffff     call sym.plouf_std::string_std::string
|      |    0x08048b51      83ec04         sub esp, 4
|      |    0x08048b54      8d45f0         lea eax, [local_10h]
|      |    0x08048b57      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|      |    0x08048b5a      e8a1fcffff     call sym.std::basic_string_char_std::char_traits_char__std::allocator_char__::_basic_string
|      |    0x08048b5f      8d45ea         lea eax, [local_16h]
|      |    0x08048b62      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|      |    0x08048b65      e8c6fcffff     call sym.std::allocator_char_::_allocator
|      |    0x08048b6a      8d45f4         lea eax, [local_ch]
|      |    0x08048b6d      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|      |    0x08048b70      e88bfcffff     call sym.std::basic_string_char_std::char_traits_char__std::allocator_char__::_basic_string
|      |    0x08048b75      8d45eb         lea eax, [local_15h]
|      |    0x08048b78      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|      |    0x08048b7b      e8b0fcffff     call sym.std::allocator_char_::_allocator
|      |    0x08048b80      8b4304         mov eax, dword [ebx + 4]    ; [0x4:4]=-1 ; 4
|      |    0x08048b83      83c004         add eax, 4
|      |    0x08048b86      8b00           mov eax, dword [eax]
|      |    0x08048b88      89442404       mov dword [local_4h], eax
|      |    0x08048b8c      8d45ec         lea eax, [local_14h]
|      |    0x08048b8f      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|      |    0x08048b92      e860010000     call sym.boolstd::operator___char_std::char_traits_char__std::allocator_char___std::basic_string_char_std::char_traits_char__std::allocator_char__const__charconst
|      |    0x08048b97      84c0           test al, al
|      |,=< 0x08048b99      744a           je 0x8048be5
|      ||   0x08048b9b      c7442404fc8d.  mov dword [local_4h], str.Bravo__tu_peux_valider_en_utilisant_ce_mot_de_passe... ; [0x8048dfc:4]=0x76617242 ; "Bravo, tu peux valider en utilisant ce mot de passe..."
|      ||   0x08048ba3      c7042400b104.  mov dword [esp], obj._ZSt4cout__GLIBCXX_3.4 ; [0x804b100:4]=0
|      ||   0x08048baa      e841fcffff     call sym.std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char___std::operator___std::char_traits_char___std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char____charconst
|      ||   0x08048baf      c74424045088.  mov dword [local_4h], sym.std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char___std::endl_char_std::char_traits_char___std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char ; [0x8048850:4]=0xb04425ff
|      ||   0x08048bb7      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|      ||   0x08048bba      e881fcffff     call sym.std::ostream::operator___std::ostream_____std::ostream
|      ||   0x08048bbf      c7442404348e.  mov dword [local_4h], str.Congratz._You_can_validate_with_this_password... ; [0x8048e34:4]=0x676e6f43 ; "Congratz. You can validate with this password..."
|      ||   0x08048bc7      c7042400b104.  mov dword [esp], obj._ZSt4cout__GLIBCXX_3.4 ; [0x804b100:4]=0
|      ||   0x08048bce      e81dfcffff     call sym.std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char___std::operator___std::char_traits_char___std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char____charconst
|      ||   0x08048bd3      c74424045088.  mov dword [local_4h], sym.std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char___std::endl_char_std::char_traits_char___std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char ; [0x8048850:4]=0xb04425ff
|      ||   0x08048bdb      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|      ||   0x08048bde      e85dfcffff     call sym.std::ostream::operator___std::ostream_____std::ostream
|     ,===< 0x08048be3      eb24           jmp 0x8048c09
|     |||   ; CODE XREF from main (0x8048b99)
|     ||`-> 0x08048be5      c7442404658e.  mov dword [local_4h], str.Password_incorrect. ; [0x8048e65:4]=0x73736150 ; "Password incorrect."
|     ||    0x08048bed      c7042400b104.  mov dword [esp], obj._ZSt4cout__GLIBCXX_3.4 ; [0x804b100:4]=0
|     ||    0x08048bf4      e8f7fbffff     call sym.std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char___std::operator___std::char_traits_char___std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char____charconst
|     ||    0x08048bf9      c74424045088.  mov dword [local_4h], sym.std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char___std::endl_char_std::char_traits_char___std::basic_ostream_char_std::char_traits_char ; [0x8048850:4]=0xb04425ff
|     ||    0x08048c01      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|     ||    0x08048c04      e837fcffff     call sym.std::ostream::operator___std::ostream_____std::ostream
|     ||    ; CODE XREF from main (0x8048be3)
|     `---> 0x08048c09      bb00000000     mov ebx, 0
|      |    0x08048c0e      8d45ec         lea eax, [local_14h]
|      |    0x08048c11      890424         mov dword [esp], eax
|      |    0x08048c14      e8e7fbffff     call sym.std::basic_string_char_std::char_traits_char__std::allocator_char__::_basic_string
|      |    ; CODE XREF from main (0x8048ae9)
|      `--> 0x08048c19      89d8           mov eax, ebx
|       ,=< 0x08048c1b      eb75           jmp 0x8048c92
..
|       |   ; CODE XREF from main (0x8048c1b)
|       `-> 0x08048c92      8d65f8         lea esp, [local_8h_2]
|           0x08048c95      59             pop ecx
|           0x08048c96      5b             pop ebx
|           0x08048c97      5d             pop ebp
|           0x08048c98      8d61fc         lea esp, [ecx - 4]
\           0x08048c9b      c3             ret
```

I solved it by placing a breakpoint to `0x08048b99` adress and printing the stack when I hit it using the command `pxr @ esp`
The result was :

`0xffe4a170  0xffe4a184  .... @esp stack R W 0x9f61c8c -->  (Here_you_have_to_understand_a_little_C++_stuffs)
0xffe4a174  0xffe4b367  g... edx stack R W 0x43007373 (ss) -->  ascii`

So now, I would like to solve this challenge again in a different way. I have two questions.

**First question :** At first, before solve it by this way, I tried to put breakpoint on each comparaison function and my idea was to change the rip adress like in [this video](https://youtu.be/hy81mnLMvnE?t=540).
The problem in my case is when I enter the command `dr`, I don't have the rip adress. This is the output I have :

```
hit breakpoint at: 8048b99
[0x08048b99]> dr
eax = 0xffffff00
ebx = 0xffceafa0
ecx = 0x00000004
edx = 0xffceb365
esi = 0xf7d54000
edi = 0xf7d54000
esp = 0xffceaf60
ebp = 0xffceaf88
eip = 0x08048b99
eflags = 0x00000246
oeax = 0xffffffff
```

Why I don't have the rip value ? Can you explain me how can I do that if is it possible ?

**Second question :** Is there a command in radare2 which I don't know and which allows me to print directly the value of `obj._ZSt4cout__GLIBCXX_3.4`

Comment: rip is the 64 bit instruction pointer only available on x64. Your binary seems to be x86, eip is the x86 instruction pointer. Try changing eip in a similar way. Read up on different registers available on both c86 and x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rip = x64 
eip = x86 
dr shows eip in your case

it is probably some demangled name  (not sure why radare2 inserts the GLIBC part )

but if you strip the GLIBC part you can use iD Command to demangle it to std::cout

```
[0x01012d6c]> iD cxx _ZSt4cout__GLIBCXX_3.4
[0x01012d6c]> iD cxx _ZSt4cout__GLIBCXX_
[0x01012d6c]> iD cxx _ZSt4cout__GLIBCXX
[0x01012d6c]> iD cxx _ZSt4cout__GLIBC
[0x01012d6c]> iD cxx _ZSt4cout__GL
[0x01012d6c]> iD cxx _ZSt4cout__
[0x01012d6c]> iD cxx _ZSt4cout_
[0x01012d6c]> iD cxx _ZSt4cout
std::cout
[0x01012d6c]> iD cxx _ZSt4cou
[0x01012d6c]>
```

btw i don't know why you get all that unintelligible thingies

did you analyse the executable prior to loading or after loading it ?

radare2 does a better job than what you posted  as a result of pdf

just so i wasn't deceived by some long forgotten memory i ran through hoops to fetch the 4th challenge :( and loaded it in radare2 and i am sure  it really does a better job than you posted in case after analysis you don't get intelligible output check

e asm.demangle and set it to true reanlyze and do pdf

here is a screenshot the first _Z blah blah in your screen shot is std::cerr auto demangled by radare2

[image]

my radare2 version atm is 2.8.xxx i see latest is 3.2.xxx if the latest version differs in output try contacting the radare2 team 
maybe someone from the team or a more avid user like megabeets might chime here too